# How to Route message from file to Azure Event Hub Using JAVA Program

Tags: java, azure, events, apache-camel

```
//SimpleRouteBuilder

import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;

public class SimpleRouteBuilder  extends RouteBuilder{

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        
        from("file:d:/InputFolderForCamel").split().tokenize("\n").to("jms:queue:javainuse");
        
    }
//MainClass

SimpleRouteBuilder routeBuilder = new SimpleRouteBuilder();
        CamelContext ctx = new DefaultCamelContext();
        
        //configure jms component        
        ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://0.0.0.0:61616");
        ctx.addComponent("jms", JmsComponent.jmsComponentAutoAcknowledge(connectionFactory));
        
        try {
            ctx.addRoutes(routeBuilder);
            ctx.start();
            Thread.sleep(5 * 60 * 1000);
            ctx.stop();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

It is working fine with ActiveMQ.

I would like to write same java program with Azure Event Hub. File must be readed by Camel and routed to Azure Event Hub

Comment: Yes. I already gone through these documents. I am trying to put the file in a particular location and it should be read by camel and will be send to azure event hub. I am confused with the URI pattern used in to() method of RouteBuilder

Comment: https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/azure-eventhubs-component.html

Answer (score 1):

```
from("file:d:/InputFolderForCamel").split().tokenize("\n").
  to("azure-eventhubs://[namespace/eventHubName][?options]");
```

URI FORMAT: azure-eventhubs://[namespace/eventHubName][?options]

In case you supply the connectionString, namespace and eventHubName are not required as these options already included in the connectionString.

For example: `azure-eventhubs://camel/camelHub?sharedAccessName={your-SASpolicyName}&sharedAccessKey={your-SASaccessKey}`

If you want to use raw connection string, it would be `azure-eventhubs:?connectionString=Endpoint=sb://{your-namespace-name}.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName={your-SASpolicyName};SharedAccessKey={your-SASaccessKey};EntityPath={event-hub-name}`

You can obtain `sharedAccessName` and `sharedAccessKey` values from Azure portal -> Your Event Hub namespace -> 'Shared Access Policies' blade.

[image]

Read more about event hub URI for Camel [here](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/azure-eventhubs-component.html#_uri_options).

Comment: from("file:d:/InputFolderForCamel").split().tokenize("\n").to("azure-eventhubs://VEventHub1/events?SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=/u3kTw4qp3lntET3gJPGh5gVn2pc8Xr3iLB4tIq23c4=");

Comment: It is also not working. It is showing end point not detected

Comment: from("file:d:/InputFolderForCamel").split().tokenize("\n").to("azure-eventhubs:?connectionString=Endpoint=sb://vhub1.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=/u3kTw4qp3lntET3gJPGh5gVn2pc8Xr3iLB4tIq23c4=");

Comment: Both are wrong!. 1st one should be `"azure-eventhubs://VEventHub1/events?sharedAccessName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;sharedAccessKey=/u3kTw4qp3lntET3gJPGh5gVn2pc8Xr3iLB4tIq23c4="`

Comment: 2nd one (connection string) does not have `EntityPath` defined. It should be `Endpoint=sb://vhub1.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=/u3kTw4qp3lntET3gJPGh5gVn2pc8Xr3iLB4tIq23c4=;EntityPath={event-hub-name}`

Comment: 2nd One is working. In 1'st case it is showing error eventHubName is null. Thanks a lot.

Comment: First one should work if you have provided namespace and eventhub name correctly in `azure-eventhubs://[namespace/eventHubName][?options]`. Also, updated the answer to include raw connection sring.

Comment: If it helped, please consider [accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) to conclude the thread.